# How do I neatly flow website link texts across multiple lines?

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]

In the above picture, you can see a huge gap between "Source:" and the website link text, even though I have only put a single space there. I would like the text to flow nicely. I have tried adding discretionary hyphens directly after "en-us/" and after "library/" because those would be nice text breaking points. However, this doesn't work at all. The only thing that seems to work, is to simply remove the space, in which case you get the following:

[image]

This is less than ideal as now there is no room at all. This problem occurs in multiple places in my document, is there a way to fix this so the text flows neatly across multiple lines?

For your information, the text is size 9 Corbel and the text boxes are 58mm wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Paragraph Style options and at the **Justification Tab**, increase the **Maximum Letter Spacing** percentage:

[image: Justification]

Comment: But now the text gets pulled apart a lot, isn't it possible to let the text break further along the link? The text seems to be behaving very strangely, either jumping apart very far or being spaced out a lot. In an ideal situation, I would have "Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/" on one line and the rest below it. In terms of spacing this should be no problem but InDesign doesn't allow me to do this, even when I decrease tracking.

Comment: Maybe you should try modifying the maximum and desired space.

Comment: Ah yes! After I also changed the Desired letter spacing, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: You could also consider using *Align Left* for the website link style for a more robust solution (it's *Justify* alignment which causes the giant space). And/or you could insert a *Discretionary Hyphen* where you want the line to break.